# Maximizing Sum of Products

Tags: dynamic-programming, mergesort, greedy

This problem was a part of Uber coding test. Please have a look and suggest a solution.

Given a zero base indexed array **A** of **even length**. Your task is to maximize the cuteness of the given array **A** which is **initially 0**. To incresase the cuteness you perform the following sequence of operations until Arr becomes empty:

1. Choose an index i in range [0,k-2], where k is the length of the array before the operation.
2. Increase the cuteness by the product of 4 consecutive integers placed at indexes
   i-1 , i, i+1& i+2. i.e  `cuteness=cuteness+Arr[i-1]*Arr[i]*Arr[i+1]*Arr[i+2]`.

(Take Arr[-1]=1 in case you choose i=0 and Arr[k]=1 in case you choose i=k-2)

3. Remove the elements at index i & i+1 from the array.

Output the maximum cuteness.

Input constrains:
**Length of array is even** `2<=n<=1000, 0<a[i]<=100`, where n is the length of the array & a[i] represents element at ith index of the array.

Sample test Case 1:

input    :  Arr={1,2,3,4}

output :  28

Explanation: Choose i=1 at first step. cuteness becomes 24. Array becomes {1,4}.
Choose  i=1 at second step.Cuteness becomes 28.Array becomes empty.

The brute force recursion is not optimal.I tried a greedy solution for this approach but it is incorrect. Probably the solution requires a DP or merge sort approach.

```
public static int maximizeCuteness(int[] arr) {
        int cuteness = 0;
        int n = arr.length;

        while (n > 0) {
            int maxCuteness = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int maxIndex = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++) {
                int tempCuteness;
                if (i == n - 2) {
                    if(n==2) {tempCuteness=arr[i] * arr[i + 1];}
                    else tempCuteness = arr[i - 1] * arr[i] * arr[i + 1];
                }
                else if (i == 0) {
                    if(n==2) {tempCuteness=arr[i] * arr[i + 1];}
                    else tempCuteness = arr[i] * arr[i + 1] * arr[i + 2];
                }  else {
                    tempCuteness = arr[i - 1] * arr[i] * arr[i + 1] * arr[i + 2];
                }

                if (tempCuteness > maxCuteness) {
                    maxCuteness = tempCuteness;
                    maxIndex = i;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(maxIndex+" "+maxCuteness);
            cuteness += maxCuteness;
            n -= 2;
            removeElements(arr, maxIndex, maxIndex + 1);
        }

        return cuteness;
    }
```